# Not able to change ownerships of a file

Tags: unix, chmod

```
[vg324y@ulpv0143 ~]$ chown root hello.txt

chown: changing ownership of `hello.txt': Operation not permitted

[vg324y@ulpv0143 ~]$ chown ia982p hello.txt

chown: changing ownership of `hello.txt': Operation not permitted
[vg324y@ulpv0143 ~]$
```

Also, the files are not having the immutable bit set.

```
[vg324y@ulpv0143 ~]$ lsattr hello.txt
-------------e- hello.txt
```

Could someone please help resolving the above?

Comment: can you please show the details of file. just ls -l  the file.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using sudo?
Like

`sudo chown ia982p hello.txt`

Further, you can change the immutable bit by using the `chattr` command:

`chattr +i hello.txt` for setting it and

`chattr -i hello.txt` for unsetting the immutable flag

After executing the first command, your immutable flag should be set:

`# lsattr hello.txt
----i--------  hello.txt`

I hope that's the solution to your problem!